# How to limit items from for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop, count, limit

How to limit items from for loop

```
<?php               
     for ($i=0; $i< count($contentdinamit["chart"]["songs"]["song"]); $i++ ) {
         echo'<li class="up"><a href="'
             .$contentdinamit["chart"]["songs"]["song"]["$i"]["artist_name"].'"><strong>'
             .$contentdinamit["chart"]["songs"]["song"]["$i"]["song_name"].'</strong></a><br /><a href="'
             .$contentdinamit["chart"]["songs"]["song"]["$i"]["artist_name"].'">'
             .$contentdinamit["chart"]["songs"]["song"]["$i"]["artist_name"].'</a></li>';
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: explain it please .What  you want to do??

Comment: //Set loop limit to 10
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10;  How It Works ?

Comment: You should NOT count() in the for declaration. Count outside $count = count(...) and use it like $i<$count

Comment: @djot I upvoted you but now I think this does not really matter. PHP arrays have the size stored `count()` does not take much longer.

Comment: @PiTheNumber: So in your words it is micro optimization ;) ... but why not do many micro optimizations?

Comment: agree with djot. It has been a method that many programmers now is using. You should use the count or sizeof outside the for function.

Comment: okok, so let's use it outside. :)

Comment: Sometimes stackoverflow does not work because no one reads and votes answers. Like here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know what you mean there. But here is what I understand from your question

```
<?php     

     for ($i=0; $i< count($contentdinamit["chart"]["songs"]["song"]); $i++ ) {

     if(($i+1)<=10){//limit your item by 10
         echo'<li class="up"><a href="'
             .$contentdinamit["chart"]["songs"]["song"]["$i"]["artist_name"].'"><strong>'
             .$contentdinamit["chart"]["songs"]["song"]["$i"]["song_name"].'</strong></a><br /><a href="'
             .$contentdinamit["chart"]["songs"]["song"]["$i"]["artist_name"].'">'
             .$contentdinamit["chart"]["songs"]["song"]["$i"]["artist_name"].'</a></li>';
    }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Why do you loop over everything? Why a second counter?

Comment: sorry I have changed it. My mistake :P

Comment: If count is 1 million this will takes for ever. If you insert a break like Lucifer Orichalcum it is bad style.

Comment: how can you say that its a bad style?

Comment: Break is not bad style in general. It tends to be bad if it makes the code less readable like a goto command does so you should only use it if you need it. More about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216359/break-statements-in-the-real-world

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2657481/1017298 Kindly read this answer from that question.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want only n number of entries then limit the number of entries got from Mysql using

```
select * from table_name limit $max;
```

Comment: Nice idea. This will be the way to go if OP used mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like limit the output? Just adjust your for-loop to echo only as much entries as you want, rather than looping until the count of your array has been reached. Say you want only 5 items, then just do this:

```
$maximum = 5; // Set whatever number you want here as a maximum, and then...
for($i = 1;$i <= $maximum;$i++) {
    // Echo goes here
}
```

Comment: that does not fix it. You have to use min(), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9094385/956397

Answer (score 0):

If you feel your code produced too much output, do something in your loop like:

```
if($i > 10)// 10 is your limit.
     break;
```

Comment: That would be useful in a foreach loop, but in a for-loop you can just set the stopping condition as the 2nd argument.

Comment: @PiTheNumber: I didn't say that this answer is wrong, it's just not really efficient if you can set the same in the for-loop arguments. This is just unneccesary extra lines of code.

Comment: @Oldskool and it is bad style.

Comment: `if($i > 10)` this will stop at the 11th item?

Answer (score 0):

> Set loop limit to 10 for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; How It Works ?

Setting the loops limit you have to specify the number of loops in the `loop continuation condition`;

```
for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

To limit it to 20 items. Try

```
$limit = min(20, count($contentdinamit["chart"]["songs"]["song"]));
for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++ )
```

Comment: Dont understand why this has been down voted. I think this is a good answer. But I prefer to use `if($i+1 <= 10)` than this. Well I think its depends on the programmer style.